# Nested Query Update in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the follow query:

```
SELECT `peers`.uid, `user`.userid FROM `peers`, `user` WHERE `user`.userid = `peers`.uid
```

the FF. is the result of the query

```
userid,uid
1,1
1,1
1,1
3,3
96,96
96,96
```

To update the result of that, I have the ff query setup:

```
UPDATE `user`
   INNER JOIN (    
   SELECT `peers`.uid, `user`.userid FROM `peers`, `user` WHERE `user`.userid = `peers`.uid
       ) AS my_current_select ON `user`.userid = my_current_select.userid
   SET `user`.credits = `user`.credits + 0.25
```

However, the update query update only 3 times, each plus once 0.25 credits into userID 1,3,96

This is not what I want. I want to uniquely add 0.25 credits into each row result of the query.
For example:

```
UID 1: UID1.credit = UID1.credit + 0.25 * 3 
UID 3: UID3.credit = UID3.credit + 0.25 * 1 
UID 3: UID96.credit = UID96.credit + 0.25 * 2
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: This can easily archive by get the result of the query and loop it. However the performance of that is out of question. I am trying to do this in 1 query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps change your inner query to:

```
SELECT `user`.userid, COUNT(`peers`.uid) as count 
FROM `peers`, `user` 
WHERE `user`.userid = `peers`.uid 
GROUP BY `user`.userid
```

to get:

```
userid,count
1,3
3,1
96,2
```

And then in your master query do:

```
UPDATE `user`
   INNER JOIN (    
   SELECT `user`.userid, COUNT(`peers`.uid) as count 
    FROM `peers`, `user` 
    WHERE `user`.userid = `peers`.uid 
    GROUP BY `user`.userid
       ) AS my_current_select ON `user`.userid = my_current_select.userid
   SET `user`.credits = `user`.credits + 0.25*my_current_select.count
```

Comment: This is perfect :) Thank you very much. Very easy to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `user`
SET credits=credits+0.25
WHERE userid IN (
    SELECT `user`.userid
    FROM `peers`, `user`
    WHERE `user`.userid = `peers`.uid
)
```

This is called a *nested query*, as you correctly surmised. In fact, the only reason you need the join at all is because you're selecting only entries present in *both* the `user` and `peers` tables (it's an implicit inner join).

If you just want to update all the users, regardless of whether they're in `peers`, you could do:

```
UPDATE `user` SET credits=credits+0.25
```

Comment: This cause: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause`.  MySQL does not allow this kind of query? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
update u
set u.credit = u.credit + (0.25 * c.credits)
from user u
join (select us.userid, count(p.uid) as credits
      from user us join peers p on us.userid = p.uid
      group by us.userid) c
     on u.userid = c.userid
```

Really, the backticks are quite unnecessary unless your table names contain special characters or reserved words.  I also prefer to put the SET clause first, which I think helps with readability (stating what you intend to do first, before the data source is defined.)  Also, I strongly recommend using real join syntax (ON) over using the where clause, and your life will be much simpler if you use aliases.